# Finding a functional that stays non-negative on a particular subset of $L^2[0, 1]$

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-measure, continuity, positivity

Start with the Hilbert space $L^2([0, 1])$ with Lebesgue measure. Fix some Borel-to-Borel measurable function $f: [0, 1] \times [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I present 4 scenarios, each more restrictive (and hence more likely to give a positive answer) than the previous one.

1. $f(\cdot, y)$ belongs to $L^2([0, 1])$ for all $y \in [0, 1]$.
2. $f$ is bounded.
3. $f$ is continuous.
4. $f$ is continuous and for all non-zero $g \in L^2([0, 1])$ the integral $\int f(x, y) g(x) dx$ attains value $0$ only finitely many times.

In each of these scenarios I ask the following question: does there necessarily exist a non-zero element $g \in L^2([0, 1])$ such that $\int f(x, y) g(x) dx \ge 0$ for all $y \in [0, 1]$?

Comment: At least for 3. the answer is negative with a fairly simply counterexample: just arrange all the cosines and sines from the basis for $L^2$ with positive and negative signs as $f(x, y_n)$ for different $y_n\to 1$, connect them continuously and multiply by something  positive converging to $0$ to get continuity at $1$. Then the function $g$ would have to be orthogonal to all of them (since we include them with both positive and negative sign), hence zero.

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks for solving fist three.

Comment: And, well, the answer for 4. is also obviously negative (if such functions $f$ exist at all): give such an $f$, just consider $yf(x, |y|)$ on $[-1, 1]$ and then rescale $[-1, 1]$ to $[0, 1]$. For any $g$ the number of zeroes is at most doubled plus $1$, so still finite, and again all the integrals have to be zero, hence $g$ is identically zero

Comment: Right, that solves it.

Comment: What if $\int_0^1 f(x, y) dy=0$ for all $x$?